# codeigniter email->attach errors

Tags: codeigniter, email, error-handling

I'm wondering how I might catch email class errors prior to codeigniter actually sending.

For example, if the function cannot find the attachment, it would seem that there isn't an error that gets thrown within the framework (at least that I can determine).

```
$this->email->attach('/path/to/file.ext');
```

I've tried:

```
if( !$this->email->attach('/path/to/file.ext') ){ 
  echo $this->email->print_debugger();
}
```

and no error is thrown.

I only notice that the attachment isn't attached after the send command is issued `$this->email->send();`

In fact, the email is sent, but obviously without the attachment, but also without the `$this->email->message()` content -- just an empty email body.

It would seem that the print_debugger() function really doesn't get populated until the send() function is called. If I intentionally point to a file that doesn't exist, the print_debugger() function will throw this error (only after the send() function is called):

```
Unable to locate the following email attachment: /path/to/file.ext<br />Your message 
has been successfully sent using the following protocol: sendmail<br /><pre>
User-Agent: CodeIgniter
Date: Thu, 23 May 2013 09:27:49 -0400
<snip>
```

When I call the print_debugger() function prior to the send() function, the result is only an empty array (I'm guessing, as the output from that call is just `<pre> </pre>`).

I'm hoping to catch this error prior to the send() function being called from within the framework.

I do understand that I can use PHP natively to check for file_exists, but it'd be nice, IMHO, for codeigniter to throw some error earlier than it does.

```
if( file_exists('/path/to/file.ext') ):
    $this->email->attach('/path/to/file.ext');
else:
    echo 'ERROR';
endif;
```

Thoughts/Suggestions/Comments?

Answer (score 0):

This isn't CodeIgniter specifc per-se. I think you are looking for [PHP Exceptions](http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php). Example:

```
try {
    $this->email->attach('/path/to/file.ext');
} catch (Exception $e) {
     echo 'Caught exception: ',  $e->getMessage();
}
```